# How to clear drawing on screen in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

```
import wx
app=wx.App()
dc=wx.ScreenDC()
dc.DrawLine(100,100,500,500)
dc.Clear()
```

I just draw on screen, not to create frame and draw on frame.

The line appear, but `dc.Clear()` no effect. And I can't find `Refresh()` for dc.

Please tell me how to clear the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, read the manual:
http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started

Something along the lines:

```
import wx
app=wx.App()
dc=wx.ScreenDC()
panel = wx.Panel(self)
dc.DrawLine(100,100,500,500)
dc.Clear()

# and then
dc.Refresh()

app.MainLoop()
```

`clear()` only "removes" the items from the next render batch.
It's not until you call `Refresh()` that these instructions are sent to the rendering memory (in non technical terms.. because that's not the order of which things go down but it's a illustration of how it happens)

There's also a function called `RefreshRect()` which, refreshes only a given area of your screen giving you faster rendering times for larger applications.
Both work just fine.

Mainly because you normally create objects within another objects in WX, i really do hate WX syntax but try this:

```
import wx

class DrawPanel(wx.Frame):

    """Draw a line to a panel."""

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, title="Draw on Panel")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 4))
        dc.DrawLine(0, 0, 50, 50)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = DrawPanel()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Taken directly from school: http://wiki.wxpython.org/VerySimpleDrawing

Comment: @user2354526 now when you mention it the second time, the main application doesn't have a `Refresh()` because that's an object function to clear it's internal stuff. Create a canvas or in my second example a frame that acts as a placeholder for the stuff you do within it. You normally do it this way (creating a wx.Frame that wraps everything).

Comment: Thank you! I just draw on screen, not to create frame and draw on it

Comment: Yes but you would have to over-write your line with something new each time. See it as a black hole, you put something in and it will stay there untill you place something ontop of it... that's your `dc` variable, you need to create a frame (or something) wihin your app that can refresh it's content. Or switch to `Pyglet`, it's muuuch friendlier in the logic department. or go with `Tkinter` the default Python library (built in)

Comment: @user2354526 yw, don't forget to mark your answer as solved if any answer suffices.

Comment: @user2354526 You found it ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to read this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/4AHOiJh75No

there is script made by wxpython developer and i think have same need with you:

```
import wx

class FancyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP |
                          wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR |
                          wx.FRAME_SHAPED,
                          size=(width, height))
        #self.SetTransparent(180)
        b = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
        dc = wx.MemoryDC()
        dc.SelectObject(b)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush('black'))
        dc.Clear()
        dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 4))
        dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, width-20, height-20)
        dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
        b.SetMaskColour('black')
        self.SetShape(wx.RegionFromBitmap(b))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.Show(True)

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        """quit if user press Esc"""
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 27:
            self.Close(force=True)
        else:
            event.Skip()

    app = wx.App()
    f = FancyFrame(300, 300)
    app.MainLoop()
```